# Get the callback while removing tag using bootstrap tag manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried with "fillInputOnTagRemove" to get the callback while removing the tag using bootstrap tag manager. Here is the [link](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3). But it is not working and also tried with click binding listener also. It is also not working. I tried with following way

```
$(".tm-input").tagsManager({
  maxTags: 5,
  fillInputOnTagRemove: function() {
  //some content goes here
  return true;
 }
});
```

and

```
$(".tm-tag-remove").bind("click",function(){
 console.log("Removed tag");
});
```

what is the best way to perform some actions while removing the tags? please share your thoughts.

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.tm-input').on('tm:spliced tm:popped', function () {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Other supported events u can find in tagsManager src

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/37okL66t/

It works if you are using latest 3.0.1 version, in older versions event names differ (`tm:afterPop`, `tm:afterSplice`). Will be useful to look into the source code of your version

Comment: Thank you for immediate response. It is not working.

Comment: You are welcome ;) Mark the question as answered if you have solved the problem